# How to connect to MySQL from Chrome App?

Tags: php, mysql, interface, navigation, google-chrome-app

How do I connect to MySQL database from the Chrome App?

Comment: Too broad. Narrow it down to something answerable. Also, turn off the caps lock.

Comment: Don't use all-caps in normal text. It's the equivalent of shouting in writing. Don't use txt-speak either, as that makes it harder to read. Just use normal English and formatting.check how to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote MySQL JavaScript Driver for Chrome Apps: https://github.com/yoichiro/mysql_js_driver Chrome Apps have an ability to connect to server with raw socket with chrome.sockets.tcp API. My driver code is using the API to communicate to MySQL Server directly.

Also, if there is your MySQL Server in a firewall, and if you can connect to the MySQL Server via SSH2, my Chrome MySQL Admin app would be good sample code: https://github.com/yoichiro/chrome_mysql_admin For instance, this app can be connected to the MySQL Server via SSH2 Port Forwarding with libssh2 written by C++.

And, if you can write code with PHP to proxy requests/responses between your Chrome Apps and your MySQL Server, you can develop APIs with PHP, and APIs can be used with Ajax from your Chrome Apps.

Comment: Thank you @Yoichiro . I wish u could break it down a little like w3cschool lessons. Can u simplify by demonstration with s simply example ?

Comment: This would be become the reference for you... https://github.com/yoichiro/chrome_mysql_console

Comment: @YoichiroTanaka, Wow, did you like just wrote an entire MySQL connector in JavaScript?